# Status bar back to previous app from multiple open apps

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am working on a project, in which I have requirement of switching from one app to another app.

When I go the second app from the first app, on the status bar of the second app, there is an option to go back to the first app. But when I go to the third app from the second app and come back again from the third app to the second app, Now on the status bar of the second app, there is the option of going to the third app, not the first app. How to show always first app's back option on status bar?

Comment: @dfd The question is about the standard iOS feature. There is no need to post any code. A 3rd party app has no control over this iOS feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is standard iOS behavior. When one app launches another app, iOS shows the previous app in the status bar to make it easy for the user to return to the previous app.

So if App A launches App B, while in App B the user will see the reference to App A in the status bar. If App B then launches App C, the status bar updates to show App B in the status bar.

At this point, if the user taps that link in the status bar the user is returned to App B and no link appears in the status bar any more.

If instead, the user does something in App C to launch App B, then the user goes to App B but the status bar link will now show App C.

This is how iOS works and nothing can be done to change it.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.. you understood my question and answered well. But what should I do now to show the link of first app instead link of App C on the status bar?

Comment: As I said, you can't. iOS will only show whatever app launched the current app and iOS clears it anytime the user uses the link. Since you are launching C from B, the link to A is gone for good.

Comment: Can you please tell me, Is this possible to hide only back option of status bar without hiding full status bar?

Comment: No. It's a feature of iOS. Your app has no ability to change the behavior.

Comment: I guess this has not changed in 18 months, RM ?  :O    @rmaddy

Comment: @Fattie iOS 13 is still the same way from what I have seen.