# is it possible to hide the backlink button on ios?

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking

Is it possible to hide the backlink button on ios?  Specifically I mean the button in the top left you see after tapping a deeplink in one app that opens another app.  In the image it shows as "Deeplinks1".

[image]

Comment: I think it is not possible and it has been answered before here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124329/2894790

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into `IOS`. There is no way to disable this feature as it has nothing to do with `flutter` or even programming with `swift`.

Answer (score 0):

This is default iOS behavior, and hiding backlinks is not recommended. Even if you achieve it in whatever way, the app will be rejected on apple store

Answer (score -2):

This answer could not be the best, but I used it before.
When you pop a page, the os(doesn't matter ios or android) will show a back button.
In this case, I used a property in the parent that tells which page should be rendered and totally forgot the pop method. for example:

```
_page == 1 ? pageOne() : _page == 2 ? pageTwo() : errorPage(),
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: He is not asking about the back button. But the "return to previous application" button.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis I read the question again, I think that, that < sign will do what I said!!